# searching different models in haystack whoosh

Tags: django, django-haystack, whoosh

i am using haystack and whoosh , but it only displays the results of one model , i made the index classes for the 3 models i need ,and i can choose the model i want to search in my templates , but only one model return results , the other models dont display results , but if i entered a query which is in my database it doesnt return no results found , it doesnt return anything , but if i entered a query which doesnt belong to the database it returns no results found . why arent the results displayed ?? sorry for bad description and thanks for help

Comment: Was the issue ever resolved or not ?

Answer (score 0):

Are you able to see the idex when you run ./manage.py rebuild_index ? Check in the template ,display for all type of indexes. And putt some description with some code that u use then it will be easy to debug.